# regex for getting URLs fails

Tags: python, html, regex, url

I found a [regex for getting urls from pages](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls):

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

But, I am not able to apply this in python. Even declaring a variable containing this expression fails with an "invalid syntax" message:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  6 2013, 09:55:21) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = "(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»""'']))"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = "(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»""'']))"
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I gave it a try [here and it worked well](http://www.pythonregex.com/). Has anyone an idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex string ends at the double quotes at the end of `;:'"`, so that's why it's a syntax error.

pythonregex.com automatically adds a \ to escape the ", producing:

```
regex = re.compile("(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))")
```

Note that that has `;:'\"` instead of `;:'"` . I'm surprised that whoever wrote pythonregex.com decided to add that escaping for you rather than letting it give you a syntax error.

I found that on my interpreter I needed to use the python `r"raw string syntax"` to make it work:

```
In [31]: string="foo.com/blah_blah kuhiuh www.example.com"

In [32]: In [29]: regex = re.compile(r"(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))")

In [33]: regex.findall(string)
Out[33]: [('foo.com/blah_blah', '', '', '', ''), ('www.example.com', '', '', '', '')]
```

Not sure which of the characters is making the r necessary but there sure are some odd ones in there.

Comment: sounds reasonable, though. But using the escaped version leads to an empty result list of regex.findall("http://foo.com/blah_blah")

Comment: Curious. Looking into it now.

Comment: I got it to work by using the raw string syntax when inputting the regex rule. Editing answer.